# Is vector X in the set W?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a homework problem that asks me the following:

Let matrix *W* be a set of all vectors of form {(a-2b), (3b), (-2a)} where *a, b* are arbitrary reals. Is vector [-5,  8, -2] in set *W*?

What I believe I should do, according to the in-class example, is choose a number for either A or B that makes the equation equal to the corresponding number in the vector. So for *a-2b*, I set *a* = 0 and *b* = 5/2; *b* = 8/3 for *3b = 8*; and *a* = 1 for *-2a* = -2.

Am I correct in thinking this is how I should approach this problem? If not, what are my next steps?

Comment: Sort of. You need the *same* value of $a$ and $b$ for all three coordinates (e.g. it's not allowed to  set $a = 0$ for the $a - 2b$ coordinate, and set $a = 1$ for the $-2a$ coordinate). So, the question is, can you set one value for $a$ and one value for $b$, so that all three coordinates give the desired value?

Comment: @user837206 if I do, will that be all that I need to do for this problem?

Comment: Yes, that's right. If you could find one value for $a$ and one value for $b$ that produces the all three coordinates, then that would prove the vector lies in $W$. However, in this example, you should be able to prove that it's not possible to find a single value of $a$ and $b$ that works for all three coordinates, which will prove the vector definitely **does not** lie in $W$.

Comment: @user837206 Thank you so so much!

Comment: No worries! Glad I could help.